# Loading WP core Thickbox through frontend

Tags: core, thickbox

Looking through some of the top Google results, this question has been answered a number of times, but the answers given don't seem to be working in my WP 3.6 install.

One solution given is this:

```
function my_thickbox() {
   if (!is_admin()) {
      wp_enqueue_script('thickbox', null,  array('jquery'), true);
      wp_enqueue_style('thickbox.css', includes_url('/js/thickbox/thickbox.css'), null, '1.0');
   }
}
add_action('init', 'my_thickbox');
```

Another was this: `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_thickbox' )`.

I've also tried using this `add_thickbox()` with no success.

All of these approaches seem to successfully load `thickbox.css`, but no JS file is showing up. I can manually go and include the path to `thickbox.js`, but that seems less desirable given that all of this seems to be handled by the core in `script-loader.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a call of `wp_footer();` function. Do it before closing body tag in your `footer.php` file. It should look like this:

```
        <?php wp_footer(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using a child theme of WP 2012. Definitely already has `wp_footer()` call.

Comment: Then `thickbox.js` has to be at the bottom of a page, because it is rendered in the footer. Can you see it there?

Comment: Narrowed down the issue to de-registering `jquery` and re-registering with the Google CDN. Removing that functionality in the child resulted in thickbox loading correctly.

Comment: Don't re-register `jquery`, it's a bad habit. Shame on you :)

Comment: If WP core would use a CDN, maybe I wouldn't have to. LOL! But if it's gonna break other functionality, I s'pose I can live with it.